# program google maps undo button behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

My program is putting markers on all points of the polylines.

I'm using the insert_at  & set_at listeners to update my markers when the user is moving these points to a new location.

Google maps API v3 provides an undo button when drawing a polyline.

It works fine with set_at (repositioning my marker to it's original position); it does however not work with insert_at.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Is there a way to program behaviour of the undo button so I can remove the marker when using the undo button?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the `remove_at`-event, it will fire when the usage of the undo-button will remove a point of the path